# How to get batch element in single element using for each in XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, soa, osb

I have a requirement in SOA/XSLT to get the batch elements record in a single element using XSLT, below are the input file and applied XSLT details. please help me out to get as expected format.

Source File-:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.org"
            targetNamespace="http://www.example.org" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="Receive1_Read_InputVariable">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="part">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="Root-Element">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Test" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name="C1" type="xsd:integer"/>
                          <xsd:element name="C2" type="xsd:string"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Target File-:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.org"
            targetNamespace="http://www.example.org" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="Payment">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>A sample element</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="File" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Batch" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
       <xsd:complexType>
       <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="BatchH" minOccurs="1"  type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="Entry" minOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="NOC" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string"/>
              <xsd:element name="BatchC" minOccurs="1" type="xsd:string"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:complexType>
           </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="FileC" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Used XSLT:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator" xmlns:oracle-xsl-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas" xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue" xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction" xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org" xmlns:oraxsl="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java" xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions" exclude-result-prefixes=" oracle-xsl-mapper xsi xsd xsl ns0 socket dvm mhdr oraxsl oraext xp20 xref"
                    xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
                    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                    xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Test/BPELProcess1"
                    xmlns:plt="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/"
                    xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/file/Test/fileReference"
                    xmlns:jca="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/wsdl/jca/">
       <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
          <!--SPECIFICATION OF MAP SOURCES AND TARGETS, DO NOT MODIFY.-->
          <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
             <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="WSDL">
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../WSDLs/BPELProcess1.wsdl"/>
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="Receive1_Read_InputVariable" namespace="http://www.example.org"/>
             </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>
          </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
          <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets>
             <oracle-xsl-mapper:target type="WSDL">
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../WSDLs/fileReference.wsdl"/>
                <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="Payment" namespace="http://www.example.org"/>
             </oracle-xsl-mapper:target>
          </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets>
          <!--GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 12.2.1.4.0(XSLT Build 190828.0353.3300) AT [TUE JUN 28 14:52:16 IST 2022].-->
       </oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
       <!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->
       <xsl:template match="/">
             <ns0:Payment>
                <xsl:if test="/ns0:Receive1_Read_InputVariable/ns0:part/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Test/ns0:C1 = &quot;1&quot;">
                   <ns0:FileHeader>
                      <xsl:value-of select="concat (/ns0:Receive1_Read_InputVariable/ns0:part/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Test/ns0:C1, /ns0:Receive1_Read_InputVariable/ns0:part/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Test/ns0:C2 )"/>
                   </ns0:FileHeader>
                </xsl:if>
           <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:Receive1_Read_InputVariable/ns0:part/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Test">
                <ns0:Batch>
                   <xsl:if test="starts-with (/ns0:C1, &quot;5&quot; )">
                      <ns0:BatchH>
                         <xsl:value-of select="concat (/ns0:C1, /ns0:C2 )"/>
                      </ns0:BatchH>
                   </xsl:if>
                   <xsl:if test="starts-with (/ns0:C1, &quot;6&quot; )">
                      <ns0:Entry>
                         <xsl:value-of select="concat (/ns0:C1, /ns0:C2 )"/>
                      </ns0:Entry>
                   </xsl:if>
                   <xsl:if test="starts-with (/ns0:C1, &quot;7&quot; )">
                      <ns0:NOC>
                         <xsl:value-of select="concat (/ns0:C1, /ns0:C2 )"/>
                      </ns0:NOC>
                   </xsl:if>
                   <xsl:if test="starts-with (/ns0:C1, &quot;8&quot; )">
                      <ns0:BatchC>
                         <xsl:value-of select="concat (/ns0:C1, /ns0:C2 )"/>
                      </ns0:BatchC>
                   </xsl:if>
                </ns0:Batch>
           </xsl:for-each>
             <xsl:if test="starts-with (/ns0:Receive1_Read_InputVariable/ns0:part/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Test/ns0:C1, &quot;9&quot; )">
                <ns0:FileC>
                   <xsl:value-of select="concat (/ns0:Receive1_Read_InputVariable/ns0:part/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Test/ns0:C1, /ns0:Receive1_Read_InputVariable/ns0:part/ns0:Root-Element/ns0:Test/ns0:C2 )"/>
                </ns0:FileC>
             </xsl:if>
          </ns0:Payment>
       </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Received Output Format-:

```xml
    <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <ns0:Payment xmlns:jca="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/wsdl/jca/" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/file/Test/fileReference" xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Test/BPELProcess1" xmlns:plt="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org">
       <ns0:File>1012880044418 09100001921101NV                 </ns0:File>
       <ns0:Batch/>
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:BatchH>5200NV               3880044418WEBSP       211209000017000001</ns0:BatchH>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:Entry>6261224007241234567890123456700100000 1013ONM               S 109100001173</ns0:Entry>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:NOC>799R010000576953      12240072                                            0910000123</ns0:NOC>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:Batch>82000122400720000000175670000000000003418                         091000010000001</ns0:Batch>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:Batch>5200NV ENTH SPPCO               3880044418MT       2112090001091000017000002</ns0:Batch>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:Entry>626122400724123456789012345670000033OR              R 1091000012072183</ns0:Entry>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:NOC>799R010007      12242                                            091000012072183</ns0:NOC>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:BatchC>82002400720000000162820000000000003880044418                         091000010000002</ns0:BatchC>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch/>
    </ns0:Payment>
```

Required Format-:

```xml
    <?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
    <ns0:Payment xmlns:jca="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/wsdl/jca/" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/file/Test/fileReference" xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Test/BPELProcess1" xmlns:plt="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.example.org">
       <ns0:File>10128800112130344A094101NV                       </ns0:File>
       
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:BatchH>5200NV                38800EBSPC        211209000109000001</ns0:BatchH>
          <ns0:Entry>62612240072412345678901270010SONM               S 1091000012072173</ns0:Entry>
          <ns0:NOC>799R010000019635    12240072                                            091000012072173</ns0:NOC>
          <ns0:BatchC>82000000020012240072000000017567000018                         091000010000001</ns0:BatchC>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:BatchH>5200NV                38800WPPC        2112090001091000017000002</ns0:Batch>
          <ns0:Entry>62612240074567000001628200200000 10203NOR              R 1091002183</ns0:Entry>
          <ns0:NOC>799R01000001      12240                                            091000012072183</ns0:NOC>
          <ns0:BatchC>8200000002001224020000000000003880044418                         091000010000002</ns0:BatchC>
       </ns0:Batch>
       <ns0:Batch/>
    </ns0:Payment>
```

Added -----Input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Receive1_Read_InputVariable xmlns="http://www.example.org">
   <part name="name1">
      <Root-Element>
         <Test>
            <C1>1</C1>
            <C2>012880044418 0910000192112130344A0941                   </C2>
         </Test>
         <Test>
            <C1>5</C1>
            <C2>200NV               3880044418WEBSPPC PYMT       2112090001091000017000001</C2>
         </Test>
         <Test>
            <C1>6</C1>
            <C2>2612240072412345678901234567000001756700100000 1013NM               S 1091000012072173</C2>
         </Test>
         <Test>
            <C1>7</C1>
            <C2>99R01000001963      12240072                                            091000012072173</C2>
         </Test>
         <Test>
            <C1>8</C1>
            <C2>200000002001224007200000000003880044418                         091000010000001</C2>
         </Test>
         <Test>
            <C1>5</C1>
            <C2>200NV                3880044418      2112090001091000017000002</C2>
         </Test>
         <Test>
            <C1>6</C1>
            <C2>2612240072412345678901234567000001628200200000 10             00012072183</C2>
         </Test>
         <Test>
            <C1>7</C1>
            <C2>99R01000001963577647      12240072                                            091000012072183</C2>
         </Test>
         <Test>
            <C1>8</C1>
            <C2>20000000200122400720000000162820000000000003880044418                         091000010000002</C2>
         </Test>
         <Test>
            <C1>9</C1>
            <C2>000054000022000050648000000716319000000000000                                       </C2>
         </Test>
      </Root-Element>
   </part>
</Receive1_Read_InputVariable>
```

Thanks,
Nilesh Jha

Comment: Could you please edit your question to also provide an example of an input XML document?

Comment: Yes, @ConalTuohy Added source and target file.

Comment: @ConalTuohy, added input file Could you please help in getting the expected.